# How to prevent macOS from a crash unplugging the eGPU?

Tags: macos, usb, crash, gpu

My Macbook Pro (2018) currently runs Big Sur 11.6.2 and is connected to an eGPU using USB-C. Using the disconnect function in the menu bar causes macOS to freeze, then crash when the USB-C cable is unplugged.

It is possible to shutdown macbook, disconnect USB-C cable, then power on the macbook again to disconnect the eGPU, but I think it should be possible to be able to disconnect/unplug it while macOS is running.

So, are there any ways to prevent macOS from crashing when I wish to unplug the eGPU?

Some additional research: The eGPU used is a Razer Core X and the GPU installed is an AMD Radeon RX Vega 56. Both hardware is listed as compatible on Apple on topic support-pages: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208544

Comment: It would be best to write to the manufacturer of the eGPU with your problem. If the software they provide (disconnect function in the menubar) does not work, perhaps there is an update. I don't use an eGPU, so I don't know if the disconnect function is provided by the manufacturer or as a function of macOS. Please edit your question and provide the make and model of eGPU you are using.

Comment: @IconDaemon - I have updated the question with information about hardware and Apple support list of compatible hardware. I'm waiting for an answer from Razer about the issue. I would expect from macos that such functions should not freeze macos independent of what hardware is used.

Comment: To clarify for us, because it isn't explicit in your question: in the past, before Big Sur, perhaps, the menu bar extension _worked as expected_ and the GPU would disconnect without a problem? If so, what changed between when the disconnect worked and now? Did it work under Big Sur, and suddenly stopped?